# Converting this date format

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm working with a date format that may not be standard because `strtotime` is not parsing it correctly. The format is `Sun Nov 16 10:10:10 GMT 2010`. I'm trying to convert it to `2010-11-16` using `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)` but not working. Is there a way I could make modifications to the original date string so that it's close to a standard format so `strtotime` would accept it?

Comment: [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date
>   format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the
>   number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the
>   timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

**EDIT**

I believe you will achieve what you are looking for with the dateTime class
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

**EDIT 2**

As @Mark Baker commented, the most correct function to use is `DateTime::createFromFormat` as you can see in this link:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat` is the way forward

Comment: Thanks for both answers. As it turns out, this string is compatible with `strtotime`, but I had an error up in my code that split the string in such a way that it become non-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php) **does know** how to parse your format `Sun Nov 16 10:10:10 GMT 2010` and it is parsed correctly. <kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/88369)</kbd>

Problem with your example is that date `2010-11-16` is not Sunday, but it is Tuesday, thats why you get `first Sunday from date 2010-11-16` which is `2010-11-21`. <kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/88369)</kbd>

[`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/datetime.createfromformat.php) **will return same** datetime as `strtotime()`. <kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/88372)</kbd>